# extra lines in command window output

Tags: matlab, import

I am very new to MATLAB and i am currently trying to learn how to import files in matlab and work on it. I am importing a "*.dat" file which contains a single column of floating point numbers[they are just filter coefficients I got from a c++ code] into an array in MATLAB. When I am displaying the output in command window the first line is always " 1.0e-03 * " followed by the contents of my file. I want to know what it means? When I check my workspace the array connects the correct number of inputs. My sample code and first few lines of output are below:

**Code:-**

```
clear; clc;

coeff = fopen('filterCoeff.dat');

A = fscanf(coeff, '%f');    

A

fclose(coeff);
```

**Output:-**

```
A =

   **1.0e-03 ***   <===== What does this mean?

  -0.170194000000000

                   0
   0.404879000000000

                   0
  -0.410347000000000
```

P.S: I found many options to read file eg. textscan, fscanf etc. Which one is the best to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a multiplier that applies to all the numbers displayed after that. It means that, for example, the last entry of `A` is not `-0.410347` but `-0.410347e-3`, that is, `-0.000410347`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I feel dumb for not figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is is just Matlab's display number type.   It means each of your results are scaled by that amount.

```
format longg
A
```

And see what it displays.  Look at the docs for format for other options.

Comment: The output I get is when the format is long. Its the correct output. I just was having trouble understanding the format.

Comment: @Preeti  Just so you are clear, 'format' does not change your value for A.  It is still a double.  It just controls how matlab displays it in the command window.  Long/ short is basically how many digits to show.  The extra g is fixed decimal notation instead of scientific or engineering notations.   Set the format according to your personal preference.

Comment: ok. I understand now. Even in the default format it just shows me by rounding off the end digits. but when i see it in the workspace matrix I can see all the digits.